# How can I show an enum like the Visual Studio tooltip?

Tags: vb.net, reflection

I have the following class:

```
Public Class PetClass

    Public Enum Animal
         Bird = 1
         Dog = 2
         Cat = 3
    End Enum

    Public MyPetType As Animal = Animal.Cat

    (...)
End Class
```

When I move the mouse over MyPetType, VS shows the following:

[image]

I would like to print this using Debug.

I'm using the following code to do this:

```
<Extension()>
Public Function Description(ByVal EnumConstant As [Enum]) As String
    Dim fi As Reflection.FieldInfo = EnumConstant.GetType().GetField(EnumConstant.ToString())
    Dim aattr() As DescriptionAttribute = DirectCast(fi.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(DescriptionAttribute), False), DescriptionAttribute())
    If aattr.Length > 0 Then
        Return aattr(0).Description
    Else
        Return EnumConstant.ToString()
    End If
End Function
```

Then I use it like this:

```
Dim n As New PetClass
Debug.Print(Description(n.MyPetType))
```

The output is "Cat".

When I  debug the function and hover the mouse over the last line, it shows exactely what I want to output:

[image]

However, the results of the function is "Cat" and not "Cat {3}".

How could I make it output "Cat {3}"?

Somebody suggested

```
String.Format("{0} {{{1}}}", EnumConstant.ToString(), EnumConstant)
```

But that returned

```
Cat {Cat}
```

Comment: `Return String.Format("{0} {{{1}}}", EnumConstant.ToString(), EnumConstant)` maybe?

Comment: @Craig That returns "Cat {Cat}"

Comment: Gee, if only there was a way to convert something to an `Integer`.

Comment: If you don't want to create a DebuggerVisualizer, then a simpler [DebuggerTypeProxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-debuggertypeproxy-attribute?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN) would do that nicely. You can add custom formatting etc. (not all that you can do with a custom DebuggerVisualizer, but it may be enough here).

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank you, that did the job, I have posted an answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Public Class PetClass
    '
    ' test
    '
    '  Dim foo As New PetClass(PetClass.Animal.Dog)
    '  Debug.WriteLine(foo.AsString)
    ' output:  Dog{2}

    Public Enum Animal
        none = 0
        Bird = 1
        Dog = 2
        Cat = 3
    End Enum

    Public MyPetType As Animal = Animal.none

    Public Sub New(WhichAnimal As Animal)
        Me.MyPetType = WhichAnimal
    End Sub

    Public Function AsString() As String
        Return String.Format("{0}{{{1}}}", Me.MyPetType, Me.MyPetType.ToString("D"))
    End Function
End Class
```

Generalized as an extension,

```
<Extension()>
Public Function Description(ByVal EnumConstant As [Enum]) As String
    Return String.Format("{0}{{{1}}}", EnumConstant, EnumConstant.ToString("D"))
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function Description(ByVal EnumConstant As [Enum]) As String
    Dim fi As Reflection.FieldInfo = EnumConstant.GetType().GetField(EnumConstant.ToString())
    Dim aattr() As DescriptionAttribute = DirectCast(fi.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(DescriptionAttribute), False), DescriptionAttribute())
    If aattr.Length > 0 Then
        Return aattr(0).Description
    Else

        Return EnumConstant.ToString() & " {" & GetEnumInt(EnumConstant) & "}"

    End If
End Function

Public Function GetEnumInt(Of T)(enumVal As T) As Integer
    Return Convert.ToInt32(enumVal)
End Function
```

Comment: Do you actually need the helper function, given that the argument to `Description` is already `As [Enum]`?  And if you do need it, you should probably constrain `T` to be `As Struct` (which doesn't guarantee you get an enum, but I believe it's about as far as you can go in generic constraints).